# How to make an anchor tag in HTML drop down a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<a href="">Email Management </a>
<p>IT services provide all staff with email address. On creation of your email address you have access to various Google apps like Google drive, Google calendar etc. We also provide group mailing account creation</p>

<ul class="list-unstyled" style="display:none"> 
    <li class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
        <a href="#.html">User Account Creation</a> 
    </li>
    <li> 
        <a href="#.html">Group Account Creation / Distribution List</a> 
    </li>
    <li> 
        <a href="#.html">Deactivation of users and Group Accounts</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I would like to make email Management a link and when the link is clicked it displays these list. The list would not appear until the link is clicked then it drops it down. let me give an example of a site that has what i would like to implement. this is the link http://ist.mit.edu/services

Comment: That's not what links are for. A button with JS attached would be more apprpriate.

Comment: See this http://jsfiddle.net/qmy4rjow/

Answer (score 1):

As @Paulie_D said, use a button rather than a link like below.

```js
$(".show-dropdown").on("click", function() {
    $(this).prop("disabled", true);
    $(".list-unstyled").slideDown("slow");
});
```

```css
.list-unstyled {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="show-dropdown">Email Management </button>
<p>IT services provide all staff with email address. On creation of your email address you have access to various Google apps like Google drive, Google calendar etc. We also provide group mailing account creation</p>

<ul class="list-unstyled"> 
    <li class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
        <a href="#.html">User Account Creation</a> 
    </li>
    <li> 
        <a href="#.html">Group Account Creation / Distribution List</a> 
    </li>
    <li> 
        <a href="#.html">Deactivation of users and Group Accounts</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

P.S. I have disabled the button once it's clicked as it makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

I would use jQuery's `.slideToggle()` method: https://jsfiddle.net/9rnwt0s2/